# Codemirror: hide specific pattern-based text into editor

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm running a codemirror instance read-only in XML mode.
My problem: I want to hide a specific xml attribute (into the editor) every time it appears, when the istance is just started, something like:
Input:

```
<node1 xxx="y" abc="1">
  <node2 yyy="z" abc="2">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </node2>
</node1>
```

What I want to see into editor:

```
<node1 xxx="y">
  <node2 yyy="z">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </node2>
</node1>
```

Any way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the attributes' pattern (possibly using the [searchcursor addon](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_searchcursor), and then use [`markText`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) with the `collapsed` option to hide them.

Comment: Thanks, but if I launch cm.getSearchCursor("MYSTRING") it returns only true or false. How can I know the position/line of the matched element?

Comment: You _could_ try reading the documentation, which I helpfully linked in my original answer.